# Run .EXE programmatically from SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Is possible to execute a CMD command using C# from a SharePoint 2013 Project WebPart/Timer Job?

I tried the following:

```
string commonFilesPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.System);
ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
proc.FileName = commonFilesPath + "\\cmd.exe";
proc.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;

proc.Arguments = "/C cd C:\\Folder && ftpclient.exe -area=SomethingThatCanChange -login=**** -password=***** -exitonupload";

using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(proc)){
   exeProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

Outside the Sharepoint Project - I've tested in a Web Forms project - this worked perfectly. When deployed to SharePoint, don't. No exception is thrown.

I must execute the .exe file (ftpclient.exe) periodically using values from sharepoint lists. What can I do?

Comment: "Don't work" is not explanation of problem. Make sure to check logs to see if there are any exception and update post with your findings. Also consider having less layers to upload to FTP: you have 3 now (cmd -> exe -> ftp), really `FtpWebRequest` may be enough, but at least run exe directly to get good error information.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov The exe throws no error. It execute perfectly outside SharePoint Project (as I said, on a Web Forms aplication).

Comment: http://www.bing.com/search?q=where+to+find+sharepoint+log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to call this .exe on as schedule then you should run the whole process outside of SharePoint. An external application can interact with a SharePoint list using the Client Side Object Model (CSOM) or using the REST API. You can then use Windows Task Scheduler to run this as required.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912(v=office.15).aspx#BasicOps_SPListItemTasks

If you absolutely have to run this inside of SharePoint then ensure that you are using a Full Trust solution and not a Sandbox solution.